# makefile module compiling gfortran in fortran 90

Tags: module, makefile, fortran90

I try to use the makefile to link up some modules to the main program.

I have a module called SimParam_mod.f90 which has:

```
MODULE simParam
  integer, parameter:: yDim = 80
  integer, parameter:: xDim = 80

  integer, parameter:: iterper = 100
  integer, parameter:: tMax = 2000
END MODULE simParam
```

After compiling it using the make option:

```
MODDIR =../module 
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)
OBJDIR=obj
LIBDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lm

CF=gfortran
CFLAGS=-I.

OBJ = main.o D2Q9Const_mod.o SimParam_mod.o 


%.o: %.f90
        $(CF) -c -O3 -o $@ $< -I$(MODDIR)

run: $(OBJ)
    $(CF) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

the values stored for **iterper** and **tMax** are not updated. I save it correctly and the modules compiled with gfortran -c  don't see any problem and the create the .mod files.

I checked the .mod files and they store it with values which are not the ones specified in the module.f90, iterper = 1 and tMax = 20 and should be 100 and 2000 respectively. All what I can say is that I don't know really how to use the make instructions and that these wrong values that get stored are former values that I had defined much earlier.. there is something that I miss..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Puigar

Comment: Delete all the `.mod` files you can find and all the `.o` files.  Build again anew.

Comment: it then appears an error that the main program doesn't recongize the modules because they are not prevoiusly compiled, may I need to compile them separately first?

Comment: ok, problem solved, I just had to compile first the modules and then the main. Thanks anyway

Comment: I can change update the values of the modules, but I need to erase the .o .mod everytime to get my parameters updated. Why is this happening?

Comment: It sounds to me as if your make process isn't over-writing the existing `.mod` and `.o` files when it runs.  The reason that I am commenting rather than answering is that I do not offer make expertise here on SO.  Use your favourite search engine or wait for someone else to spy your question and attempt to give you an answer.

Comment: I know Make, but not FORTRAN. Try this: calculate a checksum of `SimParam_mod.o`, modify `SimParam_mod.f90`, then `make SimParam_mod.o`. *Exactly* what does it say? If it says "gfortran -c -03 -o SimParam_mod.o SimParam_mod.f90 -I../module", then check the timestamp of `SimParam_mod.o`, take a new checksum and compare.

Comment: how do I calculate a checksum of something? why I should do this for? I have tried to understand the concept, but I really have a lack of knowledge on this area..

Comment: A checksum is a way of determining whether a file has been altered; a timestamp is similar, but not quite as good. They are useful, but we don't really need them. When you modify `mod.f90` and `make mod.o`, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add as Mark said a command in the makefile to delete the .o and .mod files and to recompile the program. In that case works perfectly.

just adding:
    rm -f *.o

Thanks to all the guys that were interested in the thread!

Puigar